# Changes To Spring @Autowired From Spring Boot 2.5.6 to 2.6.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have a Spring Boot App packaged as a war file and deployed on Wildfly. When I update the Spring Boot version from 2.5.6 to 2.6.2, I see lots of exception with Spring Autowire of variables. The problems being reported are circular dependency.

Has something changes with new version of Spring that changes how the autowiring works? I tried to research and can find no mention to changes in that area.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that with the new Spring Boot version, circular dependencies are not allowed by default. Check the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default).

You can get back to the previous behaviour setting the following configuration:

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references: true
```

However, I would suggest you revisit the application design.

Comment: When did circular dependencies* were allowed? I work in and old-ish project on Spring Framework 4.3.8 and they are not allowed (Project brakes on startup), but I haven't done much in Spring boot

Comment: That happens because you are using constructor injection; if you use other types of injections you should not find this problem since the dependencies will be injected when they are needed and not on the context loading. As of Spring Boot 2.6.x avoiding the issue by not using constructor injection is no longer allowed by default.

Comment: Ok, so , for example, using field injection would allow me to avoid the problem as long as the injected bean is not required in the constructor? That is, it won't give the error if the injection finishes before any call to the injected bean. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Exactly. Circular dependencies might not be a problem if you do not use constructor injection. In this case, they are injected whenever they are needed and not at construction time.